# input type radio styling on firefox OS not working

Tags: css, firefox-os

I'm trying to style input radio buttons with this code:

```
input[type="radio"] {
height: 25px;
width: 25px;
}
```

On Safari, Chrome it's working fine and the radio buttons are showing a little bigger. How can i make it to work in firefox OS as well?

Thanks for your help.

Best regards
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

If you size down your radio you will see the style is actually working.
I believe their is a max width/height set on radio type.  Try this:

```
input[type="radio"] {
height: 40px;
width: 40px; 
max-width: none;
max-height: none;
}
```